# MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser. Can't see implementations of methods and properties.

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I tried to play with *MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser* (using MonoDevelop 5.9.6 on OSX 10.10), to decompile and see how some of the commonly used by me types are implemented. However I didn't manage to see ANY of them as many of them are with atribute `[MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` (from what I know - that means that implementation is inside CLR, correct me if I am wrong), or I simply cant see the body of any method or property, as in this example (it is `System.Mathf.Max(int, int):int`):

```
[ReliabilityContract (Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static int Max (int val1, int val2);
/* body decompilation failed: 
ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerException: Error decompiling System.Int32 System.Math::Max(System.Int32,System.Int32)
 ---> System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
  at (wrapper alloc) object:AllocVector (intptr,intptr)
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder+StackSlot.ModifyStack (StackSlot[] stack, Int32 popCount, Int32 pushCount, ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ByteCode pushDefinition) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.StackAnalysis (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition methodDef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.Build (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition methodDef, Boolean optimize, ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody (IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition methodDef, ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition methodDef, ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.CreateMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method, IEnumerable`1 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.CreateMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition methodDef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.AddMethod (Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition method) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser.DomMethodNodeBuilder+<Decompile>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder b) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.AssemblyBrowser.DomMethodNodeBuilder.Decompile (Mono.TextEditor.TextEditorData data, Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition currentType, System.Action`1 setData, ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  */
```

or sometimes no exception is thrown:

[image]

**So does anyone know how to see implementation code using these tools? What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks.

Comment: if an exception is thrown, please file a bug here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ (product: Xamarin Studio)

Comment: Then I will, but the problem was that I thought this exception is something intended, like the library is protected somehow. Thanks.

Comment: if the exception is "intended", still the program should tell you that it's not possible to decompile it, and state the reason